# Can't make Executable JAR file with library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to export my project as executable jar, and all is good except one thing: there are 2 windows - the first is main jframe and second is jframe for making 3D surfaces using jzy3d library; the first window contains button "Show" for executing the second jframe. When I execute this project in Eclipse it works good, but when I make executable jar it is executed, but if I click by "Show" button the second jframe doesn't open. So, please, tell me, how can I fix it?

UPDATE: the info from cmd:

```
Catched FileNotFoundException: C:\destination-natives-windows-i586.jar (═х єфр
ё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы), while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of jar:file:
:/destination-natives-windows-i586.jar!/ (file:/C:/ + destination-natives-wind
s-i586.jar)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no glue
n-rt in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLo
erBase.java:454)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.
va:59)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JN
ibLoaderBase.java:90)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase
ava:328)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibr
y(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:390)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$2.run(Platform.java:249)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.loadGlueGenRTImpl(Platform.java:231)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:183)
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:99)
        at org.jzy3d.global.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:12)
        at org.jzy3d.global.Settings.getInstance(Settings.java:21)
        at com.nda.fuzzy.views.SurfaceViewerFrame.<init>(SurfaceViewerFrame.ja
:102)
        at com.nda.fuzzy.views.MainFrame$26.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:579
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknow
Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown So
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown So
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown So
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post your error/stack trace please.

Comment: I haven't got any messages in executing

Comment: Instead of double-clicking on the jarfile, open a terminal window (aka console or CMD or command prompt), `cd` to the directory containing the jarfile, and run `java -jar yourjarfilename.jar`.  Then you'll see the error messages in the terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

Probaly on command line you did not specify the classpath for jzy3d library

You can run a jar file with lib:

```
"java -cp libs/* -jar program.jar"
```

where you put your lib (jzy3d.jar) in the libs folder

If you have used some special tool that creates an executable jar file,
then you have to configure that tool to include the jzy3d.jar lib to be used inside the exe.

Comment: I make JAR through Eclipse without using command line. Can you help me with it?

Comment: has the excecutabel jar file, file extension .jar or .exe ? Do you click from explorer or from within exlipse?

Comment: executable file has jar extension. I click from explorer, from eclipse I execute it as project

Comment: create a batch file myStart.bat which calls  "java -cp libs/* -jar program.jar". Then clock on the batch file. first try to start from command line, then when you are able to do that, try the batch file.

Comment: You don't need the batch file if you specify the classpath in the jarfile's manifest.

Comment: Also I need to add some project to my one in Eclipse. Is it the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do one of the following:

1. repack the contents of each jarfile dependency in your own executable jarfile
2. use an .exe wrapper such as Launch4j to pack your jarfiles into a self-extracting-and-launching executable
3. include the jarfile dependencies in the Class-Path attribute of your MANIFEST.MF when creating the executable jarfile from Eclipse, and include those dependencies in the appropriate relative location when you distribute your application

Of the above options, 1 might be the easiest and most convenient for you.  If you extract the contents of the jarfile dependencies into an Eclipse project, it is then very easy to include those resources when you create your jarfile using Eclipse's wizard.

Options 2 and 3 are also pretty straightforward but I would recommend making an ant script so you can have a 1-click build.

Comment: Please look at my stacktrace